# getting godmin-tags gem errors on starting rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I get the following error when I try to start up rails or if I run `rails console`.

`.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@adventure_map/gems/godmin-tags-1.0.1/lib/godmin/tags/helper.rb:11:in '<module:Godmin>': uninitialized constant Godmin::FormBuilders (NameError)`

I have included the gem `godmin-tags` , using `haml` for templating and running rails-5.0.1

No issue has been raised on its github page and I can seem to find a solution to this

Part of my Gemfile is:

```
gem 'godmin-tags'
gem 'godmin' # administrative interface https://github.com/varvet/godmin
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'omniauth'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you include `godmin-tags` **after** `godmin` ;-)